# change download folder to external sdcard in ttpod

Tags: sd-card, music-player, downloading

I am new user of Sony C6603, with Android 4.2.2. For free music download, I use TTPod. I find the music can be downloaded for free in this App, but I wonder if I can change the default download folder (/storage/emulated/0/ttpod) to somewhere external sdcard (/stroage/sdcard1)? Or maybe such a change prevent some functions of this app?

Answer (score 1):

1. Press 3 line button beside TTPod to open the menu
2. Press "Settings"
3. Press "Downloads"
4. Press "Audio auto download directory" and select where you want to save your files