# insufficient space with space plenty available

Tags: insufficient-memory

My tablet has internal memory of 4g and external (not sd card) memory 32g.
When downloading apps are stored only in the internal memory and nothing to the external.
How to direct my downloads to the external card ??
Thanks

Comment: Also see: [change download folder to external sdcard in ttpod](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/50408/16575) / [Change attachment download folder](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/51652/16575) / and [more](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=download+external+answers%3A1).

Answer (score 1):

Normally Android will install a large app to external storage when necessary, and when possible. Not all apps support external storage.

What you'll need to do, rather than have Android do the work for you, is go to the Application settings panel (the exact location of which will depend on what version of Android your tablet is running), swipe left or right until you see a list of apps with checkboxes next to them; the top of the list should read "SD Card." These are apps you can move to external storage. You'll have to do this one at a time, I'm sorry to say, but each one will clear internal storage.

In case you're curious, external storage and/or an SD card is treated separately from internal storage. It's like having a second hard drive on your computer. **You** have to manage it.

Answer (score 1):

Or simply, There is an app for this. App2SD. Try using that to migrate apps from internal to external storage. However there's a limitation. Samsung/HTC, Huawei, LG, Xiaomi, Asus with android 6+ isn't supported. Try your luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your system mount the external storage as a SD Card but sometime is not clear enough.

Go to parameter => Application => on the SD card and tell to the system to put the available application on this available storage.

The better solution is : open  root access on your tablet and put a SD linker application for distribute the  data on the booth storage. That's depending if you've enough skill to do that.

In hoping that help.

Comment: I have no idea how to do it, but any way I'll try